# When I am using mvn clean install to build my project I get: 'npm install' failed

Tags: maven, npm, plugins, build

```
[INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[INFO] npm ERR!     C:\Users\kchheda\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-17T07_17_33_367Z-debug.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.847 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-17T12:47:36+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.9.1:npm (npm install) on project 
supplierportal: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

There is the problem in npm or plugin, but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: First I would recommend to upgrade the frontend-maven-plugin to the most recent version...and run your build with `mvn -X ...`